# Why am I getting a 'client has run out of available brokers to talk to' error when connecting to a kafka container in go-app container on Docker?

Tags: docker, go, apache-kafka

Can not connect to kafka container from another container (go-app).

I got error like this in go-app container:
`2023/05/28 09:54:44 failed to init resource, error : kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: dial tcp 172.22.0.5:29092: connect: connection refused broker === kafka:29092`

Here is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - go-tech-test

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: true
    networks:
      - go-tech-test

  redis-datastore:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-datastore
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - go-tech-test

  go-grpc:
    container_name: go-grpc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/go_app.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - go-tech-test
  
networks:
  go-tech-test:
    driver: bridge
```

and I use sarama lib to connect go app to kafka producer

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

type Resource struct {
    RedisConn     *redis.Client
    KafkaProducer sarama.SyncProducer
}

func initResource(cfg Config) (Resource, error) {

    redisConn := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     cfg.Redis.Host,
        Password: cfg.Redis.Password,
        DB:       0,
    })

    saramaCfg := sarama.NewConfig()
    saramaCfg.Producer.Return.Successes = true
    saramaCfg.Producer.RequiredAcks = sarama.WaitForAll
    saramaCfg.Producer.Retry.Max = 1

    fmt.Printf("broker === %v \n", cfg.Kafka.Broker)

    kafkaConn, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer([]string{cfg.Kafka.Broker}, saramaCfg)
    if err != nil {
        return Resource{}, err
    }

    return Resource{
        RedisConn:     redisConn,
        KafkaProducer: kafkaConn,
    }, nil
}
```

config file:

```
grpc_port : "8080"

redis:
  host: "redis-datastore:6379"
  password: ""

kafka:
  broker: kafka:29092
```

I've tried changing docker-compose file to accept broker listeners from internal and external based on this blog
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/
but the same issue still persisted.

Comment: Kafka's normal port is 9092; your configuration has an extra "2".

Comment: isn't it okay if I used any port since I have 2 listeners one for internal and external ?

I've tried using port 9092 but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, turns out port 29092 not yet available when docker run my app.
Adding this in docker-compose.yml works

```
restart: unless-stopped
```